# How to call AppRegistry.registerComponent with some delay

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I need to read some user settings before App initialize. This settings will update the style of the app.

I called AppRegistry.registerComponent with some delayed but app crashed. Have found this issue on https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17724 but nothing helps.

Answer (score 1):

I found answer

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent("App", () => App);
AppRegistry.registerRunnable(appName, initParams => {
    setTimeout(
        () => AppRegistry.runApplication("App", initParams),
        5000
    );
});
```